# Monotone approximation by Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For any $\phi\in C_b(X)$, where $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Why does the sequence $$ \phi^k(x)=\sup_{y\in X}(\phi(y)-kd(x,y))$$
converge to $\phi$ from above with $k\to\infty$? Intuitively it is clear, that one wants to make the latter term small since it is negative but I just can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:  At the first step, we note that the sequence $\{\phi^k\}$ is decreasing due to
$\phi(y)-(k+1)d(x,y)\le \phi(y)-kd(x,y)$.
And second, since $\{\phi^k\}$ has a lower bound $\phi$ due to

$\phi^k(x)\ge \phi(x)-kd(x,x)=\phi(x)$.

So, by the two above arguments, we imply that $\phi^k\to \phi$. It is just sufficient to prove that $\phi(x)$ is the greatest lower bound for the sequence $\{\phi^k(x)\}$. To see this, one assumes that there exists $\lambda$  such that $$\phi^k(x)\ge\lambda> \phi(x)~~~(1) \equiv sup_{y\in X} (\phi(y)-kd(x,y))>\lambda$$  which gives that there is an sequence $y_k\in X$ such that $$\frac{\phi(y_k)}{k}-d(x,y_k)> \frac{\lambda}{k}$$ since $\phi$ is bounded by taking limit as $k\to\infty$ one has $d(x,y_k)\to0$, i.e, $y_k\to x$. On the other hand already we have $\phi(y_k)\ge\phi(y_k)-kd(x,y_k)>\lambda$. Taking limit as $k\to\infty$ derives that $\phi(x)\ge\lambda$ which is contradicts (1).

Comment: this is incomplete, e.g. $\phi(x)-10$ is also a lower bound, but $\phi^k \not\to \phi(x)-10$

Comment: Thanks, very nice. I was wondering, if there was an $\epsilon$ kind of proof, i.e. making $k$ large enough such that the latter term in the supremum would dominate $\phi$ so the only choice for the supremum to be realized would be $y=x$.